# Displaying an image from a URL using javascript/jquery in FormAssembly

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce

I'm not a Javascript developer. Hoping to get a little help with using Jquery.

FormAssembly allows the use of Javascript, to display images from URL fields, on a pre-filled FormAssembly form. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work the way that I need it to.

I'm pre-filling two hidden FormAssembly fields, with publicly available URLs, from Salesforce.com. Let's call these two fields tfa_1 and tfa_2.

I'd like to use JavaScript to render the images from these URLS, into specific text fields in the form. Let's call these fields tfa_3 and tfa_4. Both tfa_3 and tfa_4 are populated with the following html

```html
<img src=“” alt=“” >
```

I found a similar example from FormAssembly, but their use case is slightly different than mine. When I try the Javascript in their article, the image displays at the very top of the form, and not in the fields where I need to them be displayed. Javascript example: https://www.formassembly.com/blog/display-salesforce-data-on-website/

Any advice would be much appreciated.

I tried to use this Javascript sample from this article: https://www.formassembly.com/blog/display-salesforce-data-on-website/

```
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  // the script needs to run after all our DOM elements are done rendering
  window.onload = function() {
  // htmlArr with store all img elements
    const htmlArr = $('.htmlContent > img');
  // srcArr with store all URL values for the image. Change tfa_X to the ID of your URL field.
    const srcArr = $('input[id^=tfa_X]');
    for (var i = 0; i < htmlArr.length; i++) {
      // In a loop, we are replacing sec property of img elements with the URL from the    corresponding text field
      htmlArr[i].src = srcArr[i].value;
    };
  };
</script>`
```

Comment: "with publicly available URLs, from Salesforce.com" There's a good chance that you could run into CORS problems (that have no fix) trying to do this.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Salesforce.com allows users to create publicly available URLs to files saved in an Salesforce.com org. These URLs have an expiration date, and can be password protected.

In this scenario, the file would be an image, that we'd like to display in a FormAssembly form.

Comment: So maybe you won't, but maybe you will